# La migration de laravel 5.7.28 no hace la relación de muchos a muchos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, artisan

He intentado crear la migración con relacion de muchos a muchos y desde luego usando la palabra reservada FOREIGN KEY, y claro también de manera secuencial para que no me marque error de que no existe ninguna de las dos tablas que quiero relacionar con la tabla pivote. Aqui el error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table role_user add constraint role_user_user_id_foreign foreign key (user_id) references users (id))`
A continuación los archivos de migración exactamente secuencial:

**create_users_table**

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('second_last_name');
        $table->string('pro_license')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**create_roles_table**

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**create_role_user_table**

```
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('description');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
```

Se que hay post similares a este pero sólo eran detalles con la orden de la creación de las tablas o el tipo de dato que resolvía sus problemas, yo cambie del método `Increments()` a `BigIncrements()`. La versión de MYSQL es 5.7.26 Y PHP 7.2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las tablas se crean si mayor problema, lo que no hace es crear el constraint foreign key en la tabla create_role_user_table

Comment: ¿Probaste con `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');`? Si te funciona, házmelo saber para redactar una respuesta.

Comment: Sí, hace un rato lo probé pero aún con el mismo resultado

Comment: Tal vez mi pregunta es muy obvia, pero en ese mismo orden están los archivos de migraciones?

Comment: Sí, si lo está. Ya agregue la imagen en el post

Comment: Amigo ya encontré el problema, era simplemente agregar el Engine InnoDB a todas las tablas ya que por defecto es myisam. Y yo sólamente se lo había agregado a la tabla `role_user` causando así una inconsistencia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se hace uso del motor InnoDB en Mysql para mantener la integridad de los datos se tiene que usar en todas las tablas de esta manera `$table->engine = InnoDB`, ya que si no la agregas en una tabla que deseas relacionar, por defecto se agrega el motor Myisam, produciendo una inconsistencia y provocando el error `General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint`